# Incorrect SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got 4 tables in MS Access 2016. They are:

tblA:

```
Id Date        AmountA
1  18/8/18      10
1  18/8/18      11
2  19/8/18      10
2  19/8/18      12
```

tblB:

```
Id    AmountB
1      15
2      17
```

tblC:

```
Id     AmountC
1      2
2      3
```

I want this result:

```
Id Date Total(AmountA) Total(AmountB) Total(AmountC)
1  18/8/18 21           15                 2
2  19/8/18 22           17                 3
```

Comment: OK, so what have you tried??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to share your own personal attempt(s)? We'll gladly help you fix them, but as it stands, you haven't shared anything for us to help you with. Take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help.

Comment: Looks like 3 tables. Build an aggregate query with tblA. Build another query joining that query to tblB and tblC.

Comment: Well, I've tried like this:
SELECT tblA.Id, tblA.Date, SUM(tblA.AmountA), SUM(tblB.AmountB), SUM(tblC.AmountC)
FROM (tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.Id = tblB.Id) INNER JOIN tblC ON tblA.Id = tblC.Id
GROUP BY tblA.Id;
but that does not work

Comment: I'm sorry for not having shared what I've tried. I've copied it above. The results are something like a multiplication of the totals. Hope someone would correct it.

Comment: Add what you've tried to the question @Atiq, I can't un-downvote it until you edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select Id, max(Date) as Date, max(AmountA) as AmountA, max(AmountB) as AmountB, max(AmountC) as AmountC
FROM
(
SELECT Id, Date, sum(AmountA) as AmountA, Null as AmountB, Null as AmountC FROM tblA 
GROUP BY Id,Date
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, Null as Date, Null as Amount, sum(AmountB) as AmountB, Null as AmountC From tblB
Group by Id
UNION ALL
Select Id, Null as Date, Null as Amount, Null as AmountB, sum(AmountC) as AmountC From tblC
Group by Id
) as aggregate
Group by Id
```

This query probably has a couple errors, but the general structure should be correct. I did this a couple days ago by coincidence.